# ちょっとしか---V negative potential

Tags: grammar, particle-しか

> 「はい、遠野先輩の力になれたらいいなって思って。あ、けどちょっとしか詳しい話は聞けなかったんですけどね」
>
> I tought I could help Tohno-Senpai. But I was able to find out just a little of the full story.

Is it correct?

ちょっと=A little
しか---聞けなかった=can only hear
か詳しい話=full story

Comment: 聞けなかった is past tense, so strictly speaking "could only hear". Also delete the か on か詳しい話.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it looks like you're understanding the sentence perfectly well.